# StreamDensityPlot and its legends

Tags: plotting, color, legending, plot-themes, streams

I'm trying to plot this simple code

```
StreamDensityPlot[{x y Sin[4 x], x y Cos[4 y]}, {x, -L, L}, {y,-L,L}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, StreamStyle -> Black,  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][Rescale[#5, {0, 1.2}, {380, 750}]] &),ColorFunctionScaling -> False,PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 1.2}}], Above]]
```

However, even though I used the Colorfunctionscaling as being False, and asking later for the plotlegends, the legend bar seems not to appear. Any thoughts? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: use `PlotLegends ->  Placed[BarLegend[{"VisibleSpectrum", {380, 750}}], Above]`? (and remove the first `PlotLegends -> Automatic` in your code).

Comment: Thanks @kglr. Now I see the bars! However, I'd like to access the value of the function based on its color. When I set the bar like you did, it spans from 380 to 750 instead of from 0 to 1.2

Comment: how about `PlotLegends ->Placed[BarLegend[{(ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][Rescale[#, {0, 1.2},{380,750}]]&), {0, 1.2}}], Above]`?

Comment: Yep. That definitely worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `PlotLegends -> Automatic` and use

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[
  BarLegend[{(ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][Rescale[#, {0, 1.2},{380,750}]]&), {0, 1.2}}],
  Above]
```

to get

[image]